# android отображение статического html кода

Tags: android, android-webview

В приложение есть такие информационные страницы как например о приложении где немало форматированного текста типа списков(), заголовков(), страница в целом не большая на пол страницы.

Я разместил код таких страниц в raw файлах, потом читаю эти файлы и передаю WebView для отображения, но грузит он ее порядком секунд 3 и получается так что текста сначала нет и в течение секунд 3 он только появляется, пробовал указывать в настройках WebView setLayerType, но видимых изменений я не наблюдаю.

Какие средства в android применяются для подобных вещей?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам поможет TextView, я именно его использую для отображения HTML кода. Вот тут есть [пример](http://alvinalexander.com/android/how-show-html-string-in-android-textview-webview)

Comment: Да может быть это решит проблему, но у меня есть html теги которые не поддерживают Html.fromHtml(), поэтому нужно что то наподобие WebView но что бы не было таких задержек.

Comment: Да, к сожалению это действительно так. Пока разбирался с темой HTML вот еще смотрел что-то типа этого [Android webview slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422427/android-webview-slow) или [Android webview loading data performance very slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304237/android-webview-loading-data-performance-very-slow). Сам эксперименты не проводил.